# How to use polymorphism in embedded software?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, polymorphism, embedded-systems

I have been developing a control software in C++. From the high perspective the control task can be basically divided into several subtasks

- calculate unmeasurable physical quantity based on dynamic model of the controlled system (MachineModel)
- based on calculated quantity from previous step and reference value of the controlled variable calculate refrence value of the action variable (ControlAlgorithm)
- transform the action variable for the actuator (Modulator)

My design of the control software respects the above mentioned subtasks in such a manner that each subtask is responsibility of one class. At the same time there are several ways how to implement each of the above mentioned subtasks. It is very likely that I will experiment with various implementations. So I have been attempting to design the software in such a manner that the changes in the implementation of the above mentioned subtask (which will be done at compile time) won't influence implementation of the other subtasks.

In case I wouldn't implement the hard real time software I would define abstract class with pure virtual methods for each subtask. Individual implementations of the subtasks will be subclasses of their abstract base classes. The problem here is the timing penalty caused by the virtual methods call which I would like to avoid. Due to this fact the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) seems to me to be good solution here.

```
template <class T>
class MachineModel
{

public:
  void update()
  {
    static_cast<T *>(this)->update();
  }

  float getTransformAngle() const
  {
    return static_cast<T *>(this)->getTransformAngle();
  }

  void getRotorFlux(float &psir_alpha, float &psir_beta) const
  {
    static_cast<T *>(this)->getRotorFlux(psir_alpha, psir_beta);
  }

  void getStatorCurrent(float &is_d, float &is_q) const
  {
    static_cast<T *>(this)->getStatorCurrent(is_d, is_q);
  }
};

class InModel : public MachineModel<InModel>
{
public:
  InModel() {}

  void update() {}

  float getTransformAngle() const {}

  void getRotorFlux(float &psir_alpha, float &psir_beta) const {}

  void getStatorCurrent(float &is_d, float &is_q) const {}

};
```

The intended usage of the `MachineModel`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  InModel machine_model;

  machine_model.update();
  
  float psir_alpha;
  float psir_beta;

  machine_model.getRotorFlux(psir_alpha, psir_beta);

  return 0;
}
```

Let's say I will need other model than the "current-speed" (InModel). Let's say "voltage-current" (VIModel). Then I will define

```
class VIModel : public MachineModel<VIModel>
{
public:
  VIModel() {}

  void update() 
  { 
    // different implementation than in the InModel but same interface
  }

  float getTransformAngle() const 
  {
    // different implementation than in the InModel but same interface
  }

  void getRotorFlux(float &psir_alpha, float &psir_beta) const 
  {
    // different implementation than in the InModel but same interface
  }

  void getStatorCurrent(float &is_d, float &is_q) const 
  {
    // different implementation than in the InModel but same interface
  }

};
```

I can define several MachineModels with the same interface but various implementations. In case other objects in the control software rely on the `MachineModel` interface they don't notice any change in case I change the implementation. The same is truth for the ControlAlogrithm and the Modulator.

Do you think that the CRTP is right choice for my problem?

Comment: I have not read anything else than the title. If I am to answer just the title I would say - you should use polymorphism exactly the same way as you would use it for a non-embeded application. The polymorphism is not a cocept that makes difference on where you are running your application.

Comment: Based on what you bring to the table I do not see a compelling reason to resort to polymorphism or even use multiple classes for different stages of the calculation. Can you quantify the need for speed optimization on the level you are concerned about? It seems unlikely to me that the indirection of a method call would have a significant impact on your process. And if it does, all the more reason to inline the lot and just try to reuse intermediate results as long as they are still valid.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use CRTP? Have you measured how much impact a virtual function call has on your platform? The delay of a virtual call compared to a direct function call is fully deterministic, so the only reason to avoid virtual calls in a hard realtime system is when you are very close to your maximum response times.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thank you for your reaction. I agree with your statement that polymorphism is the universal concept. As far as I know there are two approaches how to   achieve polymorphic behavior. One called dynamic polymorphism based on the table of virtual mehods and exploiting the late binding. Another called static polymorphism based on methods overloading and avoiding the virtual methods call.

Comment: @MartinMaat the reason why I have been thinking about dividing the calculation into several classes is that I would adhere the one module one responsibility principle. The reason why I have been thinking about polymorphism is that as far as I know there is no other possibility in C++ how to achieve that several classes will have same interface.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau please see my updated question as far as the example of CRTP usage.

Comment: @Steve, I was most interested in what the calling code of thos functions in `MachineModel` would look like. That would show if CRTP really helps you or if other techniques work better.

Comment: `MachineModel` does *nothing* for you here. `MachineModel<InModel>` is no less unrelated to `MachineModel<OutModel>` than `InModel` is to `OutModel`. If you want runtime polymorphism you need a non-template base class with virtual functions which `MachineModel` implements. Otherwise just use `InModel` as a template parameter directly.

Comment: @Steve I see. But note that "module" is not necessarily a class, it can be a method too. Scattering your single responsibility over multiple modules can be worse than putting multiple responsibilities in the same module. It looks like all your code needs to be executed in sequence and each stage needs the result of the prior stage. So it is basically one task which may be split up in separate steps (methods) but there are not several entities.

Comment: "as far as I know there is no other possibility in C++ how to achieve that several classes will have same interface." Look at the standard containers. They don't have any virtual methods, but because they have consistently named methods they have a shared interface. It is static (compile-time) polymorphism

Comment: My general opinion, and I think it is consensus, is that you're pursuning "polymorphism" because you think that it should be done ... not because the actual task at hand calls for it, or necessarily can *(timing-wise ...)* afford it.  You describe three operations that must be performed in sequence.  They are very closely tied to each other – they are not at all "abstract." Hence, what is the actual advantage of abstraction?

Comment: I guess the answers (and comments) over at [your other related question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/422741/how-to-create-uniform-interface-of-c-classes-without-virtual-methods/422823#422823) didn't help much ... but they must have helped _some_.  Maybe you could elaborate here - or there - on what you've learned and what you've tried since then and thereby get a tighter focus to this question, or that one? The more precision you can give the more useful the answers you'll get.

Comment: As an alternative to polymorphism, what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400925/what-modern-alternatives-are-there-to-c-interface-ideas-by-dave-abrahams-and-c